# Cowardly refusing to install hooks with `core.hooksPath` set

Tags: python, git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I tried to run this command but it always shows this error. Help me, please!

```
$ pre-commit install
[ERROR] Cowardly refusing to install hooks with `core.hooksPath` set.
hint: `git config --unset-all core.hooksPath`
```

Comment: welcome to SO! Do you happen to have core.hooksPath configured? Check with `git config -l`

Comment: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Cowardly+refusing+to+install+hooks+with+core.hooksPath+set

Answer (score 12):

1. Run:

   ```
   git config --unset-all core.hooksPath
   ```
2. If the global core.hooksPath is not empty, run:

   ```
   git config --global --unset-all core.hooksPath
   ```

   But of course, it's global so be careful.

   Why pre-commit is nonfunctional with global hooks? see [issue](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1198)

Comment: This worked for me. But, reader, be aware that if you are using git hooks for anything in any project, this will break them.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the above error because of setting up a global hook path.

It can be resolved in below two ways: -

1. Unset the global hook path as below: -

   ```
   git config --unset core.hooksPath
   ```
2. Set local hooks path as below: -

   ```
   git config --local core.hooksPath .git/hooks
   ```

There is a very interesting conversation on this topic, I will highly recommend going through it once:-

[issue Cowardly refusing to install hooks with core.hooksPath set](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20Cowardly%20refusing%20to%20install%20hooks%20with%20core.hooksPath%20set)

Please let me know in the comments if this resolves your problem. I am super curious about it.

Comment: oh sorry! both ways failed, it's always show that error

Comment: can you please share your global git config contents

Answer (score 0):

I also hit this problem, and I'm definitely not convinced by the author's answer in [#1198](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1198). Requiring to edit a personal file/setting to be able to use a software does not seems acceptable to be me.

Anyway, the workaround I found is to prevent `pre-commit` to use global config during install phase, where you probably have setup your `core.hookspath`. As there is no option, we can trick git by telling it to use `/dev/null` as global config dir, only during install time:

```
$ XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/dev/null pre-commit install
pre-commit installed at .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

I'm not sure to fully understand the implication of doing so, but I'm aware that my global git hooks won't run anymore when `pre-commit` is enabled on a project :)

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily set `GIT_CONFIG=/dev/null` for the duration of `pre-commit install`.

```
GIT_CONFIG=/dev/null pre-commit install
```

I did not have success setting dummy `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` like previous answers suggested. Setting `GIT_CONFIG` works.

With *my* workaround, I am willing to accept the resolution on issue #1198

> no sorry, your workaround is fine and your usecase is not strong enough to warrant a complexity increase and a safety decrease

(https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1198#issuecomment-844208591)

### Don't forget to do trial commit to check that pre-commit is active

The problem with global `core.hooksPath` configured is that the global hooks (in `$HOME/.git/hooks/`) override the local ones in each repository. So, it is important to put some explicit delagation to your `$HOME/.git/hooks/pre-commit`. I placed this on top of the file (after `#!` line, ofc.)

```
# Run local pre-commit hook if it exists
if [ -e ./.git/hooks/pre-commit ]; then
  if ! (./.git/hooks/pre-commit "$@"); then
    exit 1;
  fi
fi
```

This is what I have set up.

Alternatively, you may ignore global hooks for the current repo with

```
git config --local core.hooksPath .git/hooks
```